# How can I escape these quotes in regex expressions?

Tags: c#, regex, text

I have a string text which is like:

```
  "ruf": "the text I want",
     "puf":
```

I want extract the text inside the quotes.

tried this :

```
         string cg="?<=\"ruf\":\")(.*?)(?=\",puf";
         Regex g = new Regex(cg);
```

It didnt work.

Comment: did you want ruf and puf?

Comment: Is is multi line string?

Comment: @AvinashRaj no. just the text I want (without quotes)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with below regex:

```
(?<="ruf":\s\")[^"]*
```

[Online demo](http://regex101.com/r/eJ7dN6/9)

String literals for use in programs:

C#

```
@"(?<=""ruf"":\s\"")[^""]*"
```

output:

```
the text I want
```

Pattern description:

```
  (?<=                     look behind to see if there is:
    "ruf":                   '"ruf":'
    \s                       whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ")
    \"                       '"'
  )                        end of look-behind
  [^"]*                    any character except: '"' (0 or more times
                           (matching the most amount possible))
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/Z8cRbYgBYH8tw_Xm)

---

#### EDIT

> Can you add puf. Because it is a long text which has **multiple quotes** in it

If you are looking till "puf" is found then try below regex:

```
(?<="ruf":\s\")[\s\S]*(?=",\s*"puf")
```

[Online demo](http://regex101.com/r/eJ7dN6/11)

String literals for use in programs:

C#

```
@"(?<=""ruf"":\s\"")[\s\S]*(?="",\s*""puf"")"
```

Comment: thanks. Can you add puf. Because it is a long text which has multiple quotes in it

Comment: so you are looking till "puf" is found.

Answer (score 1):

You could try the below regex with s modifier,

```
/(?<=\"ruf\": \")[^\"]*(?=\",.*?\"puf\":)/s
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/zN2vG6/13)

With the `s` modifier, dot matches even newline character also.

Answer (score 1):

Do it like this:

```
var myRegex = new Regex(@"(?s)(?<=""ruf"": "")[^""]*(?=\s*""puf"")");
string resultString = myRegex.Match(yourString).Value;
Console.WriteLine(resultString);
```